# Algorithm for optimal item selections

Tags: algorithm

I'm trying to find an algorithm for this problem. Ideally in ruby but any language would also be great:

I'm going to the shop and need to buy X grams of an ingredient.

The shop does not necessarily have an "X grams of ingredient" product.
But they have N products with different weights.

Which combination of products should I buy so I end up with at least X grams of the ingredient and the amount of ingredient the closest to X as possible?
I can select the same product several times.

---

Example 1 :

I want to buy 1.4kg of pasta.
The shop has these products:

- Product A: 1kg of pasta
- Product B: 500g of pasta
- Product C: 300g of pasta

Solution: I need to buy 1 product B and 3 products C (500g +  3 x 300g = 1.4kg)

because it's the exact amount I need.

---

Example 2 :

I want to buy 300 grams of rice.
The shop has these products:

- Product A: 1kg of rice
- Product B: 500g of rice
- Product C: 200g of rice

Solution: I need to buy 2 products C.

Because it ends up being 400g, which is lighter than 1 product B (2x200g < 500g)

Comment: If you're learning programming at college level or higher, you should take a course in [discrete mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_mathematics). It's a combinatoric exercise that should be taught in such a course. Until then, why not simply use brute-force by trying all combinations one by one?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for your comment. I don't know R at all. I didn't mention R.

Comment: I'm sorry, misread.

Comment: I think this is equivalent to the [change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem). Shop products can influence which is a good algorithm to use, _viz_ canonical if the greedy algorithm always solves problem optimally.

Answer (score 3):

You can formulate the problem as a linear integer program, which can solved using MIP (mixed-integer linear program) software.

We define three variables:

- A equals the number of units of 1000g of rice
- B equals the number of units of  500g of rice
- C equals the number of units of  200g of rice

Suppose `X` equals `5000`.

The linear, integer program is as follows.

```
minimize 1000*A + 500*B + 200*C
```

subject to:

```
1000*A + 500*B + 200*C >= 5000
A >= 0
B >= 0
C >= 0
```

`A`, `B` and `C` are further required to be integer-valued.

Answer (score 1):

Naive approach: try all possible volumes in increasing order while possible and the solution is improving:

```py
import heapq
from typing import NamedTuple, Tuple

def best_quantity(target_volume, units):
    units = set(units)
    current_best = solution(0, ())
    scheduled = {current_best.volume}  # a set of volumes scheduled to expand
    q = [current_best]  # a queue of 2-tuples: (quantity, a tuple of units making it)
    while q:
        baseline_solution = heapq.heappop(q)
        if baseline_solution.volume >= target_volume:
            return baseline_solution.units
        for unit in units:
            new_volume = unit + baseline_solution.volume
            if new_volume in scheduled:
                continue
            scheduled.add(new_volume)
            heapq.heappush(q, solution(new_volume, baseline_solution.units+(unit,)))

        scheduled.remove(baseline_solution.volume)

    # we get here if possible units are empty
    return None

# returns (300, 300, 300, 500)
best_quantity(1400, (1000, 500, 300))
```

There are better algorithms, but I'm lazy today

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution!

I tested best_quantity(300, [1000, 500, 260]) and it returned [260].
However, it should return [500] because the solution must be more or equal than the target volume.

Comment: @Julien pretty simple fix, updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

In the end, I use a similiar method to @Marat's: Trying all possible options to find the best one.
And the code looks simpler in my opinion:

```rb
class SelectProducts
  def self.call(...)
    new(...).call
  end

  def initialize(weights:, weight_required:)
    @weights = weights.sort.reverse
    @weight_required = weight_required
    @best_cart = []
    @best_weight = Float::INFINITY
  end

  def call
    weights.each do |weight|
      build_cart([weight])
    end

    best_cart
  end

  private

  attr_reader :weights, :weight_required
  attr_accessor :best_cart, :best_weight

  def build_cart(cart)
    cart_weight = cart.sum
    if cart_weight >= weight_required
      if cart_weight < best_weight
        self.best_weight = cart_weight
        self.best_cart = cart
      end
      return
    end

    weights.each do |weight|
      build_cart(cart.dup << weight)
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
SelectProducts.call(
  weights: [1000, 500, 300],
  weight_required: 1400,
)
# returns [500, 300, 300, 300]

SelectProducts.call(
  weights: [1000, 500, 200],
  weight_required: 300,
)
# returns [200, 200]

SelectProducts.call(
  weights: [1000, 500, 260],
  weight_required: 300,
)
# returns [500]
```